# Error while installing GNU Octave

Tags: apt, xubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my windows pc using Oracle VirtualBox.

I've recently tried installing Octave on my Ubuntu platform, but after a few steps it is showing some error saying unable to fetch archives.

What should I do? I've posted the image here.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run this commands with root privilages, for this purpose you can run these commands with `sudo`.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt --fix-missing install
sudo apt install octave
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it's running successfully now.

Comment: @SauravChatterjee if your problem was solved please accept this answer ; thanks

Comment: oh, that worked for me too.